# Error 404 when using pulsar admin API to get topic stats

Tags: apache-pulsar

I am trying to get the stats of all the topics in a namespace by using the pulsar admin API.
I am using Pulser 2.7.3.
I first use this request to get the name of all the topics in the namespace :
GET /admin/v2/:schema/:tenant/:namespace/getList, which doesn't work but if I remove the "getList" it works.

Then for each topic I use the request indicated in the pulsar documentation to get the stats:
GET /admin/v2/:schema/:tenant/:namespace/:topic/stats/getStats
And I get a 404 error. I have checked multiple times, and there isn't any typo or error in the schema, tenant, namespace and topic. I tried by modifying slightly the request (removing the "getStats", etc..) but it's still not working.

Any clues what might be causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

The relevant admin API is documented at: https://pulsar.apache.org/admin-rest-api/?version=2.7.3

The former API you mentioned to list topics under a namespace gives you the topic name in `[persistent|non-persistent]://tenant/namespace/topic` format from which you need to extract only the `topic` part and supply it to the `GET /admin/v2/{persistent|non-persistent}/:tenant/:namespace/:topic/stats/` API. That should give you the topic-wise stats. (Tested against pulsar 2.7.2)

Note: in case of partitioned topics, each partition is going to show up as separate topic.

Comment: Thanks ! The problem came from the fact that most of the topic are partitioned and I had to use the GET /admin/v2/{persistent|non-persistent}/:tenant/:namespace/:topic/partitioned-stats API. However, I still have one topic that isn't partitioned, and even when I use the right API I get an error. The name of the topic is "stats", so the request is GET /admin/v2/{persistent|non-persistent}/:tenant/:namespace/stats/stats. Do you think the name of the topic is what could be causing the problem ?

Comment: I don't think so. I created a topic stats that is not partitioned like so:

`curl -X PUT -v localhost:80/admin/v2/persistent/public/default/stats`

Then when I query for the stats, I do get response!

`% curl -v localhost:80/admin/v2/persistent/public/default/stats/stats`


{"msgRateIn":0.0,"msgThroughputIn":0.0,"msgRateOut":0.0,"msgThroughputOut":0.0,"bytesInCounter":0,"msgInCounter":0,"bytesOutCounter":0,"msgOutCounter":0,"averageMsgSize":0.0,"msgChunkPublished":false,"storageSize":0, ... }